# Nothig shows with places.description == "Dermatologista" ?(

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
 export default function Search({ navigation }) {
   const [state, setState] = useState({
      places: [
       {
         id: 1,
         title: 'Clinica da pele',
         description: 'Dermatologista',
         latitude:-2.42206406,
         longitude:-54.71947789,
       },
        {
         id: 2 ,
         title:'Unimed',
         description:'Hospital',
         latitude:-2.42501721,
         longitude:-54.71146077,
       },
        {
         id: 3,
         title: 'Dra. Josimar',
         description:'Dermatologista',
         latitude: -2.4288346,
         longitude:-54.7290553,
       }
     ]
```

here I will take the itens to show

```
      return(

      </View>*/
     <SafeAreaView>
       <FlatList
     styles = {styles.PlaceContainer}
     showsVerticalScrollIndicator
     data={state.places}
     keyExtractor={item => item.id}
     renderItem={({ item }) => {
```

here I tried to select the item witch the description is Dermatologista but it didnt shows anything

```
    item.description == "Dermatologista" ? (
  
    <View key={item.id} style={styles.place} >
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      <Text>{item.description}</Text>
    </View>
  ):""
```

I cant show nothing when I try to select but when it was just a return it came back all the info
}

```
}
/>

</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: try `renderItem={({ item }) => {` to `renderItem={(item) => {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You must map your data to get each value form the array

Use an array method like map you retrieve your data.

```
state.places.map((place) => {
  console.log(place);
})
```

I'm just logging here but you can put this in your react component to print out each place.